Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/style.css' because its MIME type
I'm planning to remove padding in my phaser canvas but when I use external css it doesn't work in my index.html I have the code below
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Phaser Game</title>
    <script src="phaser.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="game-container"></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

then in my syle.css file
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}




Does this answer your question? Refusing to apply styles because MIME type

It seems you are using webpack, so a solution could be,  to move the style.css into the dist folder, since there all files for the webserver are located by default (and I don't see a webpack config file).
But I'm just assuming that you are using webpack, due to your folder Screenshot (and since I added the webpack, tag to your question).
Alternative (seeing your webpack-config):

in the index.html file remove the line:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">


and in the index.js file add the line (at the beginning of the file)
import "../style.css";



Like this the styles will be inlined into the javascript file.

yes I'm using a webpack tried the solution on the link you provided but still doesn't work. I've post my webpack config

@Newboy11 I updated my answer with an alternative, were the styles are inlined into the javascript file.
